Error when I open vscode in ubuntu 24.04 lts
I have this problem when open my vscode error:

I was use
code --disable-gpu

and
    code --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer

if somebody know what happend. please... :(

Please edit your question and add the output of echo "My user ID is "$UID; ls -la ~/.config | grep Code; ls -la ~/.vscode | grep extensions; ls -la /run/user | grep 1000

If you don't provide the information I asked you to, no one will be able to help you fix your problem.
